# how to export nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, export

I have a ListPlot where I extract my data again using `pts1 = Cases[(*I put my list plot here*), , x_Point :> First@x, Infinity];` which gives me the data as nested list

```
    { {{0.03, 2.21325*10^22}, {0.06, 3.64418*10^22}, {0.1, 4.778*10^22}, {0.4, 7.90494*10^22}, 
      {1., 9.8882*10^22}, {3., 1.20734*10^23}}, {{0.03, 1.24205*10^22}, {0.06, 1.7829*10^22}, 
      {0.1, 2.14653*10^22}, {0.4, 2.96566*10^22}, {1., 3.39166*10^22}, {3., 3.80355*10^22}}, 
      {{0.03, 7.93772*10^21}, {0.06, 1.05402*10^22}, {0.1, 1.21384*10^22}, {0.4, 1.54018*10^22}, 
      {1., 1.69508*10^22}, {3., 1.83693*10^22}}}
```

How can I export this data, so that I have a file with 3x2 colums for the three data sets, so something like

```
0.03, 2.21325*10^22,  0.03, 1.24205*10^22,0.03, 7.93772*10^21
0.06, 3.64418*10^22, etc.
0.1, etc.
etc.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a comma separated list.

```
Export["~/Desktop/file.txt", Flatten /@ Transpose[pts1], "CSV"]
```

Comment: actually I need the transpose of the output file. So not 0.03 0.03 0.03 in the first column but 0.03 0.06 0.1 etc.

Comment: @user2758804 My bad, I updated the code.

Comment: Thanks. Is there an easy way to complement the output file by column labels in the first row, eg. `Hz, density(1ML), Hz, density(2ML), Hz, density(3ML)` ?

Comment: Is there an equivalent version of `Flatten /@ Transpose[pts1]` in the form `Flatten[Transpose[pts1]]`?

Comment: 1) Yes, use Prepend to add such a row to `Transpose[pts1]`.
2) No, `Flatten` works from the outside in, so I think it's not possible to do it with `Flatten` without also using `Map` (`/@`).

Answer (score 0):

```
data // Transpose // Flatten // Partition[#, 6] & // 
  Export["test.csv", #] &
```

Comment: Is there a universal version of it? e.g. which also works for 4 data sets?